# Is it safe to seed production databases with DoctrineFixturesBundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My application needs some rows to be present in some tables to function properly when it is deployed. However, I'm not sure if the [DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) is written to be run on a production server. It works perfectly fine on my development machine, but is it safe enough to use on production?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Personal experience

I have integrated the bundle alongside [`doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle) into the (continous) deployment process of several symfony2 applications since end of 2011.

I never ran into any problems with the fixtures-bundle.

I have to admit that the migrations-bundle occasionally gave me some headaches - but it meanwhile feels very mature and stable subjectively.

### General information

[`doctrine/data-fixtures`](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures) was introduced in mid 2010.

[`doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle) (the bundle to integrate with symfony2 projects) exists since mid 2011.

It is one of the **top 20 most used bundles** according to this [survey](http://symfony.com/blog/the-30-most-useful-symfony-bundles-and-making-them-even-better) by SensioLabs.

[capifony](http://capifony.org/) - the widely used deployment tool for symfony2 applications - has [builtin](https://github.com/everzet/capifony/blob/master/lib/symfony2/doctrine.rb#L95) support for loading fixtures with the bundle.

### Test coverage

`doctrine/data-fixtures` has a good [test coverage](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/tree/master/tests).

The bundle itself currently doesn't provide any tests ... but the only thing it provides is a very simple command. Have a look at the [code](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/blob/master/Command/LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php).

### Conclusion

I'd say the bundle is definitely safe for production deployments as I'm doing so for 3+ years by now.

With >2 million [installs](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle) of `doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle` via composer ... I'm definitely not the only one thinking like that.

Comment: I had no doubt about its stability, per say. What had me confused was what @matteo mentioned, namely that in the documentation, it is always used in the development environment, and I didn't know how much of those 2 million installs were on production, and which were on development machines. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: Sorry @ParhamDoustdar is not true, in the official doc of sf2 is not mentioned to enable only in dev env See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#setup-and-configuration) but on the repo history i find [this](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/commit/56b6f9e3efc2c78195cbb0fa574c39290c40e49a)(Recommend to activate the bundle only in dev environement
) commit

Comment: The default values for Doctrine also fit a development environment better than production (E.G. --append being off by default).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use if for load new (static) data in prod evironment also in conjunction of doctrine migrations.

As example, if on existent project we develop a new entity for manage a tipology (viwh or without an admin CRUD section):

- We release the migrations task
- We load an initial set of data with:

  php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append --env=prod --fixtures=src/AcmeDemoBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/ProdFixtures/NewTipology

The option `--append` permit to append the data on existent database without delete all, and the `--fixtures` can pass a folder as input for load all the preset data.

The fixture class can access on the existing data (or other container service) extending the ContainerAwareInterface.

This is my experience.

Hope this help.