# Symfony insert default data in database after force update database

Tags: php, symfony

I need insert default statuses of good (`StatusGoodEntity`) after install my application in computer any developers.
How do it with Symfony 2.8 + Doctrine?
I try use DoctrineFixturesBundle, but it purge database before insert data.
I already have production database and my new business logic requried default data in database and I cannot purge it before insert them.

How I can do it with Yii 2:

```
class m150101_185401_create_news_table extends Migration
{
    public function safeUp()
    {
        $this->createTable('good_status', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'title' => $this->string()->notNull(),
            'code' => $this->integer(),
        ]);

        $this->insert('good_status', [
            'title' => 'waiting',
            'code' => 'default',
        ]);

        $this->insert('good_status', [
            'title' => 'closed',
            'code' => 'closed',
        ]);

        $this->insert('good_status', [
            'title' => 'preparing',
            'code' => 'preparing',
        ]);
    }

    ...
}
```

After that I know ID of default statuses and I can be sure that it can be used.

Comment: You could try the `--append` flag to append data instead of purging the DB before population: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-fixtures

Comment: @kix but symfony not recommended use it in production database and this bundle include in test and dev environments. Symfony no have any solutions?

Comment: It's not about Symfony, it's about Doctrine IMO :) And I don't see any reason why using fixtures in prod wouldn't be recommended. Perhaps it's that you usually use them for tests. Here's an SO thread on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314347/is-it-safe-to-seed-production-databases-with-doctrinefixturesbundle
By the way, you could as well use `ContainerAware` migrations http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#container-aware-migrations and persist your seed data from there using an `EntityManager`.